# How to check whether various number ranges are represented in a one-dimensional array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to check whether all age groups from teen to centenarian are represented in an array.

My logic path has been:

- Create an array with pre-defined decade-based age brackets `[1, 2, 3, ... , 10]`
- Isolate the age value of each element in the sample array of objects
- Divide those ages by `10` to get what decade the age falls in
- `parseInt` that number to get an integer and put resultant figures in new array
- Compare that array with the pre-defined age bracket array created initially.

The expected output is `true` but I am instead getting `false`.

Another logic issue I am facing is that the oldest age in the sample array, `128`, reduces to `12` after dividing/parsing whereas it would be preferable for it to check if the `int` is `> 10` instead of specifically `10`.

Code below:

```
const devAges = list.map((list) => {
  return list.age
})
const devAgesDiv = devAges.map(i => i / 10);

for(i = 0; i < devAgesDiv.length; i++){
  devAgesDiv[i] = parseInt(devAgesDiv[i]);
}

function allAges(list) {
  const ageBrackets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  return ageBrackets.every((ageBracket) =>
    list.some((listItem) => listItem.ageBracket === ageBracket)
  );
}

console.log(allAges(list)); // output false;
```

Sample array below:

```
var list = [
  { firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Brazil', continent: 'Americas', age: 19, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 29, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Noa', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 40, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Andrei', lastName: 'E.', country: 'Romania', continent: 'Europe', age: 59, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Maria', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Peru', continent: 'Americas', age: 60, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 75, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Chloe', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Guernsey', continent: 'Europe', age: 88, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Viktoria', lastName: 'W.', country: 'Bulgaria', continent: 'Europe', age: 98, language: 'PHP' },
  { firstName: 'Piotr', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Poland', continent: 'Europe', age: 128, language: 'JavaScript' }
];
```

Comment: dude 128 / 10 == 12 and depending on rounding it could 13, not 10, so your 10 bracket is not represented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two updates to get the desired result:

1. `devAgesDiv` - check if the list `age` is over 100 and return 10 otherwise divide by 10; you can `parseInt` the result of that test
2. You can use `includes` in `allAges` to check `every` `ageBracket` is represented

See below:

```js
const list = [
  { firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Brazil', continent: 'Americas', age: 19, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 29, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Noa', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 40, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Andrei', lastName: 'E.', country: 'Romania', continent: 'Europe', age: 59, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Maria', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Peru', continent: 'Americas', age: 60, language: 'C' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 75, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Chloe', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Guernsey', continent: 'Europe', age: 88, language: 'Ruby' },
  { firstName: 'Viktoria', lastName: 'W.', country: 'Bulgaria', continent: 'Europe', age: 98, language: 'PHP' },
  { firstName: 'Piotr', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Poland', continent: 'Europe', age: 128, language: 'JavaScript' }
];

const devAgesDiv = list.map(item => parseInt(item.age > 100 ? 10 : item.age / 10));

const ageBrackets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function allAges(list) {
  return ageBrackets.every(ageBracket => list.includes(ageBracket));
}

console.log(allAges(devAgesDiv)); // true
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly although one issue I am facing is when I try to wrap the whole thing up as a function, I get a ReferenceError because ```devAgesDiv``` isn't defined. Is this an issue with it being classed as a local variable once it is inside the function?